# Integration of delta function of sum of square

Tags: integration

Does anyone know how to calculate
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(%
\prod_{j = 1}^{N}\mathrm{d}J_{j}\right)
\delta\left(-N + \sum_{j = 1}^{N}J_{j}^{2}\right)
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[3mm]
\mbox{or}\quad &
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{d\epsilon \over 2\pi}
\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dJ\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\epsilon\left(J^{2} - 1\right)} \right]^{N}\quad\mbox{where}\quad N \to \infty\ {\Large ?}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $\delta(f(\boldsymbol x))$ is standardly defined as
$$\int_{\mathbb R^N}
 \delta(f(\boldsymbol x)) \phi(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x =
\int_{f(\boldsymbol x) = 0}
 \frac {\phi(\boldsymbol x)} {|\nabla f(\boldsymbol x)|} dS.$$
$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{i \omega x} dx$ is meaningful if interpreted as the Fourier transform or as
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R e^{i \omega x} dx =
\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac {2 \sin R \omega} \omega =
2 \pi \delta(\omega),$$
where the limits are understood in the distributional sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral (for which you should write $\int_{\Bbb R^N}$, not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$) is the boundary of the $n$-ball $J^2=N$ of radius $\sqrt{N}$, i.e.$$\frac{2\pi^{N/2}N^{(N-1)/2}}{\Gamma(N/2)}\stackrel{N\gg1}{\sim}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}(2\pi e)^{N/2}\stackrel{\to\infty}{\to}\infty.$$You seem to already know the second integral equals the first one, because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi}e^{ik\epsilon}=\delta(k)$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I shouldn't changed the $\delta$-function in to an integral... It's simply the surface area of an $(N−1)$-sphere with radius $\sqrt{N}$... (Although the answer is actually $\frac{2\pi^{N/2}N^{(N-1)/2}}{\Gamma\left(N/2\right)}$) Thank you!!!

Comment: @Jimmy Formula corrected.

Comment: Emmm, I picked some integer $N$ & checked the integration of $\delta$-function with the '$\Gamma$-function expression' using Mathematica. The two results were slightly different... But anyway, it shall be all right when $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Jimmy I'd used the Stirling approximation, which has fractional error $\approx\frac{1}{12N}$ for finite $N$. I've changed a $\to$ to $\sim$ to avoid confusion there.

Comment: No, I meant $\int \mathcal{D}[J] \delta(-N + \sum_{J} J^2) \neq \frac{2\pi^{N/2} N^{(N-1)/2}}{\Gamma(N/2)}$... The other parts were Okay... I just series expanded both the numerator & denominator at $N = \infty$...